# OpenAI api call 405 error using next.js, typescript, and tailwind css

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I am getting a 405 error, that the method request is not allowed. I am trying to make a call to an api route when the button is clicked. That API route then calls the openai api. I am not sure where I am going wrong here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fncix.png)

```
'use client';

import { createServerSupabaseClient } from '@/app/supabase-server';
import DashboardOut from '@/components/DashboardOut';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const HumanizerForm: React.FC = () => {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');
  const [outputText, setOutputText] = useState('');

  const handleHumanize = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/humanize', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({ text: inputText })
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      const data = await response.json();
      setOutputText(data.humanizedText);
    } else {
      console.error('Failed to humanize text:', await response.text());
    }
  };

  return (
   
      <button
        className="bg-blue-500 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded"
        onClick={handleHumanize}
      >
        Humanize
      </button>
  );
};

export default HumanizerForm;
```

```
// pages/api/humanize.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const { text } = await req.json();

    try {
      const openAiResponse = await fetch('https://api.openai.com/v1/completions', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY}`
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          model: "text-davinci-003",
          prompt: text,
          temperature: 0.7,
          max_tokens: 2048,
        })
      });

      if (openAiResponse.ok) {
        const { choices } = await openAiResponse.json();
        const humanizedText = choices[0].text.trim();
        return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ humanizedText }), {
          status: 200,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        });
      } else {
        const error = await openAiResponse.json();
        return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ error }), {
          status: openAiResponse.status,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        });
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error('Error calling OpenAI:', error);
        return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({
          error: { message: error.message || 'An unknown error occurred' }
        }), {
          status: 500,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
        });
      }
      
  } else {
    return new NextResponse('Method Not Allowed', {
      status: 405,
      headers: {
        Allow: 'POST',
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
      },
    });
  }
}

export const config = {
  matcher: '/api/humanize',
};
```

I am expecting a call to be made to the OpenAI api, but instead I am getting a 405 error.

Comment: Seems like `req.method` is not returning `POST`. Could you `console.log` it to check what is the value of `req.method`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all export default your handler like this

```
export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
```

Then you should extract text from body like this

```
 const { text } = await req.body;
```